# Windows is detecting the wrong CPU temps compared to Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, cpu, cooling, temperature

I have a computer I built which has been rock solid for around a year or so and recently has been blue screening on me. When I do the usual spot checks I use new thermal grease on my H100i cooler. then do a stress test. I can see my default temp is around 50 which is a little high but it's been warmer than usual so I put it down to weather. when I run the stress test I can clearly see the CPU reaches 100c within a second of starting the test. This being odd for an H100i, i7 4770K not overclocked PC.

I try other tools and think its dodgy sensors. I then try a bootable USB Linux disk and do the same tests. To find out my Core temp at idle is 32 and my Prime95 stress test (small FFT's) is 60 odd. completely normal. Windows is incorrectly detecting my CPU temps. And I have no idea why. As you can see in the other image my PC will Jump Stright from 40-50 (which is higher than normal anyway) to 92-100c

[image: Temperature graph]

Specs: [image: System specs]

Comment: So besides the temperatures being reported as higher then they are doesnitnresult in any performance problems?

Comment: If you're worried consider replacing the thermal paste and have a look if it helps. If the sensors would be dodgy they would be in any OS. Did you make sure that they used the same settings for single/multi threading and possibly CPU frequency boosting?

Comment: Hi Both, I'm getting a blue screen which is a Watchdog_timeout problem, but I can't work out what is causing the problem. so i assume it's because the OS thinks the CPU is running to hot

Comment: @seth Hi, I've already done it was the first thing I've tried. Its windows misreading my sensor temps

Comment: Don't use speccy, use RealTemp. There are issues in many temerature reporting apps in windows.